# Get MaxHttpCollectionKeys programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In ASP.NET 4.0, is there a way to get the current  [aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) value programmatically?

I'm aware that there [appears to be a "feature"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/054888e8-1ebc-4b6f-9fac-a23ba87b758d/does-aspnet-45-enforce-maxhttpcollectionkeys-limit?forum=netfxbcl) in ASP.NET 4.5.1 where the MaxHttpCollectionKeys value is int.MaxValue instead of 1000